# how to convert a binary array with hex values into decimal and then to a string

Tags: c++

I have a binary array with hex values and I would like to convert it into decimal. Once that is done I would like to display it in a string.

BTW, I am working on an intel process via ubuntu and this will probably be used on a sun many hp unix box.

When I do a straight up assignment to unsigned long it works... as in the decimal part. I still have not made that into a string yet, but I am not sure why it works. Furthermore I read somewhere that when you put it in unsigned long the you will not have to worry about endianess.

Could I get some help on how to take this issue and why the aforementioned works as well?

please note: I am using c++ and not the .net stuff so bitconverter is not available.

**EDIT** (Copied from answer to own question below)

first of all thanks for the endian link that IBM article really helped. knowing that i was just putting it into a register rather than manually putting the byte values in consecutive memory locations is what takes away the whole endianess issue made a big difference.

here is a piece of code that I wrote which I know can be better but its just something quick...

```
// use just first 6 bytes
byte truncHmac[6];
memset( truncHmac, 0x00, 6 );
unsigned long sixdigit[6];
for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
    truncHmac[i]=hmacOutputBuffer[i];
    sixdigit[i]=truncHmac[i];
    std::cout<<sixdigit[i]<< std::endl;
}
```

the output is

```
HMAC: 76e061dc7512be8bcca2dce44e0b81608771714b
118
224
97
220
117
18
```

which makes sense that its take the first six bytes and converting them to decimals.

The only question I have now is how to make this into a string. Someone mentioned using manipulators? Could I get an example?

Comment: Post some code that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Indenting your code with four spaces per line makes it show up as code:

```
// use just first 6 bytes
byte truncHmac[6];
memset( truncHmac, 0x00, 6 );
unsigned long sixdigit[6];

for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
    truncHmac[i]=hmacOutputBuffer[i];
    sixdigit[i]=truncHmac[i];
    std::cout<<sixdigit[i]<< std::endl;
}
```

Hit the orange `?` at the top right of the editing box for markup help.

As for manipulators, use a [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) instead of `cout`:

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream strs;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    strs << hex << hmacOutputBuffer[i] << std::endl;
}

strs.str(); // returns a string object.
```

EDIT: Writing loops as `for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i <= N - 1; ++i)` will work better for you when you need to deal with C++ iterators, which define the end as "one past the last valid element".

Also, MAC addresses typically put `-` or `:` characters in between each byte.  The use of `:` is deprecated because IPv6 addresses also use `:`.

Comment: I'd be very careful with strs.str().c_str().  stringstream::str(), I believe, is allowed to return a temporary copy, and a .c_str() on top of that is getting a pointer to temporary memory.  This issue has bitten me before.

Comment: Whoever tried edit this: I was editing it a bunch at the time and don't know how to merge the edits.  Please recheck my work.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

hex, decimal and char are just a different way to present the value.
it is up to your application how to interpret the value.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on C++ [iostream manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/), especially on [hex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/).

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

IBM has a nice article on [endianness in practice](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html?ca=drs-).

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for the endian link that IBM article really helped. knowing that i was just putting it into a register rather than manually putting the byte values in consecutive memory locations is what takes away the whole endianess issue made a big difference.

here is a pc of code that i wrote which i know can be better but its just something quick...

```
// use just first 6 bytes
byte truncHmac[6];
memset( truncHmac, 0x00, 6 );
unsigned long sixdigit[6];
for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
    truncHmac[i]=hmacOutputBuffer[i];
    sixdigit[i]=truncHmac[i];
    std::cout<<sixdigit[i]<< std::endl;
}
```

the output is

```
HMAC: 76e061dc7512be8bcca2dce44e0b81608771714b
118
224
97
220
117
18
```

which makes sense that its take the first six bytes and converting them to decimals.

the only question i have now is how to make this into a string..someone mentioned using manipulators? could i get an example?

thanks a bunch guys you all rock!

Comment: Okay, you just replied in the form of an answer.  Next time, put this in a comment under the answer you're referring to (that "add comment" button below an answer) or edit your question to add the new information or question.

Comment: // use just first 6 bytes
byte truncHmac[6];
memset( truncHmac, 0x00, 6 );
unsigned long sixdigit[6];
for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
truncHmac[i]=hmacOutputBuffer[i];
sixdigit[i]=truncHmac[i];
std::cout<<sixdigit[i]<< std::endl;
}



output
HMAC: 76e061dc7512be8bcca2dce44e0b81608771714b
118
224
97
220
117
18